# print function not working python

Tags: python, printing

very new to programming not sure what is happening 
I currently have

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir (r"C:\Users\franc_000\Pictures\prank")
    print (file_list)
```

this returns nothing except for the >>> on two line in the module

Comment: You need to call the function, as - `rename_files()` .

Comment: I dont follow what youre saying

Comment: Try this as the last line after defining your function - `rename_files()` .

Comment: got it. thanks so much. Do you have an explanation as to the logic behind that/why that needs to be there?

Comment: You should start at some python tutorial or so, and there are tons of tutorials online, just search them up in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function.

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir (r"C:\Users\franc_000\Pictures\prank")
    print (file_list)
rename_files()
```